No me funciona el autoplay en la etiqueta video de html
he intentando de varias maneras que la etiqueta de "video" funcione el "autoplay" al cargar el sitio web, estoy haciendo una página web de noticias interna, y si no coloco la etiqueta "muted" no se reproduce, he intentado con javascript pero en eso estoy aprendiendo, he utilizado el siguiente código


const playSound = function() {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    element.innerHTML = `
      <audio autoplay loop>
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </audio>
    `;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    document.removeEventListener('click', playSound);
}

document.addEventListener('click', playSound);
<video autoplay controls loop>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
</video>



El video se reproduce con sonido cuando le doy click en cualquier parte del documento, pero deseo que el sonido se reproduzca al cargar la página de noticias.

Y porque no usas un mp3 para el sonido en lugar de un video mp4?? No importa que sea el mismo sonido, las cosas se deben hacer bien audio es audio y video video.

Me funciona ese tu "audio" con autoplay pero solo en modo normal, en incognito no, que raro. Si para mañana no te han resuelto le meto cabeza. Salu2

Hola, si, mi código funciona, pero cuando le doy click, lo mismo ha pasado con el ejemplo que acabo de colocar.

No es posible reproducir una pista de audio automáticamente, cualquier método para activar el audio depende obligatoriamente del algún evento que haya sido gatillado por la interacción del usuario (por ejemplo, un click).
Esto es válido para audios y videos con pistas de audio. En el caso de los videos es posible iniciar la reproducción automática solo cuando carece de pista de audio o se ha silenciado usando el atributo muted
<audio autoplay muted>

Este bloqueo nace por el abuso que algunos sitios realizaban con publicidad molesta e inoportuna, los que recuerdan la época de los 2000 sabrán de que hablo.
Por años hubo tecnicas y trucos para saltar el bloqueo, pero a la fecha ya no existe algun método que sirva (y doy gracias por ello)
Más información en: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Hola, por favor podrías ayudarme con esto, solo necesito que se reproduzca automáticamente, he estado con la guía que pasaste, pero sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar.

A mi si me lo reproduce en modo normal, de manera automática, por eso dije que a mi si me funcionaba.

Si, y realmente es bueno que te funcione, pero realmente a mi, no me funciona.
